# Cloud Composer webserver always unhealthy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow

Google cloud monitoring panel always shows webserver as unhealthy, even at timestamps before the composer is created. Is this a glitch in the monitoring panel? I can access the airflow UI without problem.